# Python abstract doc comment for method

Tags: python, abstract, pycharm, docstring

How to specify for IDE (PyCharm) and for documentation tools, that described method is abstract?

What i want:

```
class Test:
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        """
        This method must be overridden

        :abstract
        """
        pass
```

But docstring `:abstract` is not exists.

How to told to the IDE, that method is abstract and must be overridden?

Comment: Typically, a method that must be overridden will `raise NotImplementedError` rather than `pass`.

Comment: But PyCharm did not understand, that that method must be overridden

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the class a new-style class by inheriting from `object`: `class Test(object)`.  (optional, but recommended)
2. You must set the `__metaclass__` property of `Test` to `__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta`.

For more information, see the [docs on `abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html).